# DigitalOcean API Error When Creating New App - api.digitalocean.com/v2/apps

Tags: python, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

Getting an error when trying to create new PaaS app on DigitalOcean. Have already looked at [docs](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#operation/list_apps) and can't figure out why this doesn't work. The `spec` object was basically taken from docs.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_TOKEN'
}

spec = {
    "name": "test-app",
    "region": "nyc1",
    "services": [
            {
                "name": "api",
                "github": {
                    "branch": "main",
                    "deploy_on_push": 'true',
                    "repo": "username/my-app"
                },
                "run_command": "python3 application.py",
                "environment_slug": "python",
                "instance_count": 2,
                "instance_size_slug": "basic-xxs",
                "routes": [
                    {
                        "path": "/api"
                    }
                ]
            }
    ]
}

payload = {'spec': spec}

res = requests.post(
    'https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/apps',
    headers=headers,
    data=payload,
)
print(res)
print(res.json())
print(res.status_code)
```

I'm getting the following error. Is this an error with the way I'm sending data?

```
<Response [400]>
{'id': 'invalid_argument', 'message': "invalid character 's' looking for beginning of value"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. `json=payload` (not `data=payload`)
2. `deploy_on_push": True,` Boolean (not string)

Comment: Getting this error ```{'id': 'not_found', 'message': 'not found: getting app'}```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_TOKEN'
}

spec = {
    "name": "test-app",
    "region": "nyc1",
    "services": [
            {
                "name": "api",
                "github": {
                    "branch": "main",
                    "deploy_on_push": 'True',
                    "repo": "username/my-app"
                },
                "run_command": "python3 application.py",
                "environment_slug": "python",
                "instance_count": 2,
                "instance_size_slug": "basic-xxs",
                "routes": [
                    {
                        "path": "/api"
                    }
                ]
            }
    ]
}

payload = {'spec': spec}

res = requests.post(
    'https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/apps',
    headers=headers,
    json=payload,
)
print(res)
print(res.json())
print(res.status_code)
```

Comment: This works after changing to:```"deploy_on_push": True,```

Comment: @Jin You wrote True with a small t (true), but it always goes with a large T. Then the other change was also json = payload inside res = requests.post. You wrote data = payload. If my answer, or the answer of other users, was useful to you and you solved the problem, accept it as a solution to the question by marking it with a green tick, as a Stackoverflow regulation from the Help Center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer